# Find song files on the device?

Tags: android

Is there a way to discover all song files on the device? I basically want to make a list of them to show to the user (don't need to play them or anything).

I'm searching for "android sdk + song file discovery" and the like but not seeing anything related to programatically finding song files on the device.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `ContentProvider` named [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html). This might be what you want. See [this tutorial](http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/displaying-list-of-music-files-stored.html).

Answer (score 2):

[MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html)

Comment: @τεκ: Not the most detailed answer I've ever seen but +1 anyway. :-)